# Android webview <table width='100%'> issue

Tags: android, webview, html-table, android-webview

Android WebView does not accept an html which specifies width/height for the table like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
</head>
<body>

    <table width='100%' height='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This is column 1
        </td>
        <td>
            This is column 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

which works perfectly on my PC browser. WebView is set to have `layout_width="match_parent"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`, and the data is loaded using:

```
webView.loadData(data, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, needed to replace with width='100%25'.